# Dar Nome conforme numero em Array foreach

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho esse foreach abaixo que lista resultados de um Select, gostaria de dar nome conforme o número, como fiz abaixo no IF, mas ainda não funcionou..

```
foreach($result as $row)  
    {  

     $segurado[]           = $row['SEGURADO'];     
     $data[]           = $row['DATA'];     
     $status_seguro1       = $row['STATUS_SEGURO'];

        if($status_seguro1 == '1') {$status_seguro[] = 'Vistoria';}
        if($status_seguro1 == '2') {$status_seguro[] = 'Primeira Parcela';}
        if($status_seguro1 == '3') {$status_seguro[] = 'Apólice';}
        if($status_seguro1 == '4') {$status_seguro[] = 'Cancelado';}

    }
```

Comment: Não funcionar quer dizer  o que? como deveria ficar o formato final?

Comment: Se vier do BD o numero 1 no status_seguro1 deve ficar 'Vistoria' no formato final, e assim por diante...

Comment: E o que acontece com esse código? não vai o escrito? fica o número?

Comment: está dando algum erro, pois estou recebendo o numero '2' mas está aparecendo escrito Apólice (o que esta referenciado para o numero '3'

Comment: Utilize o strtr http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php

Answer (score 1):

Como nesse ifs está apenas fazendo atribuições simples, pode trocar essa abordagem por um array, então basta acessar acessar a o indice correto e já atribuir o valore respectivo.

```
$status = array(1 => 'Vistoria', 2 => 'Primeira Parcela', 3 => 'Apólice', 4 => 'Cancelado');
foreach($result as $row){  
    $segurado[] = $row['SEGURADO'];     
    $data[] = $row['DATA'];     
    $status_seguro[] = isset($status[$row['STATUS_SEGURO']]) ? $status[$row['STATUS_SEGURO']] : 'Inválido';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Porque não cria uma tabela com o status? Assim, no futuro se precisar mudar um status ou mesmo incluir um novo, basta incluí-lo no seu BD. Sem usar o banco de dados a melhor opção é a do rray.